# Flurry sample application

Tags: objective-c, flurry

how to work with flurry sdk? Is any one have idea about this.please let me know with sample code.i want to work with my iphone app.

Answer (score 2):

download  flurry sdk   from dev.flurry.com

1. **copy the sdk in to your project.**

in `appdelegate.h`

```
  #import "FlurryAnalytics.h" 
  #import "FlurryAppCircle.h"

  @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate,FlurryAdDelegate>
  {
  }
```

in `appdelegate.m`

call this  function in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
  [self flurryIntegration];


   - (void)flurryIntegration
   {
       [FlurryAnalytics startSession:flurryAppID];
      [FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleEnabled:YES]
   }
```

**IN  VIEWCONTROLLER.M**

**to log errors in flurry.**

```
 [FlurryAnalytics logError:@"1" message:exception.description exception:exception];
```

**to log events/actions**

```
  [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event name / Action name"]];
```

**to open take over**

```
    [FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleEnabled:YES];
    [FlurryAppCircle
     openTakeover:@"STORE_APP_RECOMMEND"
     orientation:@"landscape"
     rewardImage:nil
     rewardMessage:nil
     userCookies:nil];
```

**to open videotakeover**

```
    [FlurryClips setVideoAdsEnabled:YES];
    [FlurryClips openVideoTakeover:@"APP_SPLASH_HOOK"
                       orientation:@"portrait"
                       rewardImage:nil
                     rewardMessage:nil
                       userCookies:nil
                          autoPlay:YES];
```